# Find the length of the acceleration vector of the particle

Tags: vectors

Find the length of the acceleration vector of the particle which path is described by

$$r(t)=12t\cos(8t)i+12t\sin(8t)j+2\ln(t)k$$

at the point $t=5$. The answer should be a real number and given to an accuracy of $0.01$

That's the question.

What I can't figure out is what they mean by length. I tried to derive each term twice which gave me:

$$a(t) = -198(\sin(8t)+4t\cos(8t))i +198(\cos(8t)-4t\sin(8t))k + \left(-\frac{2}{t^2}\right)k$$

Pretty sure that's correct but if i take the magnitude for $t=5$

$\left|a(5)\right|=3964.95$ which apprently is not correct. Can anyone help me a bit to the path of the correct answere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get $$\textbf{a}(t) = \frac{\text{d}^2 \textbf{r}}{\text{d}t^2} = -192\Big(\sin 8t + 4t\cos 8t\Big)\textbf{i} + 192\Big(\cos 8t - 4t\sin 8t\Big)\textbf{j} + \frac{-2}{t^2}\textbf{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Cody T is right.  You'll easily derive $192^2(1+16t^2)+4/t^4$ for the length of $a(t)$.